# Logout target path do not redirect correctly in silex firewall

Tags: php, symfony, silex

I have a silex firewall with two secured areas like this

```
'clientes'      =>  array(
            'pattern'   =>  '^/clients.*$',
            'anonymous' =>  true,
            'form'      =>  array(
                'login_path' => '/clients/login',
                'check_path' => '/clients/login_check',
                'default_target_path' => '/clients/admin',
                'always_use_default_target_path' => true,
                'username_parameter' => 'username',
                'password_parameter' => 'password',
                'csrf_parameter' => 'login_token',
                'failure_path' => '/clients/login',
            ),
            'logout'    =>  array(
                'logout_path' => '/clients/admin/logout',
                'target' => '/clients/login'
            ),
            'users' => $app->factory(function () use ($app) {
                return new Lib\Provider\ClientProvider($app);
            })
        ),
        'sistema'       =>  array(
            'pattern'   =>  '^/.*$',
            'anonymous' =>  true,
            'form'      =>  array(
                'login_path' => '/',
                'check_path' => '/login_check',
                'default_target_path' => '/dashboard',
                'always_use_default_target_path' => true,
                'username_parameter' => 'username',
                'password_parameter' => 'password',
                'csrf_parameter' => 'login_token',
                'failure_path' => '/',
            ),
            'logout'    =>  array(
                'logout_path' => '/logout',
                'target' => '/'
            ),
            'users' => $app->factory(function () use ($app) {
                return new Lib\Provider\UserProvider($app);
            })
        )
    ),
    'security.access_rules' => array(
        array('^/select-locale.*$', 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'),
        array('^/recupera-password.*$', 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'),
        array('^/dashboard', array('ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_SISTEMA')),
        array('^/clients/login$', 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'),
        array('^/clients/admin', array('ROLE_CLIENTE'))
    ),
    'security.role_hierarchy' => array(
        'ROLE_ADMIN_SUPER'    => array('ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_SISTEMA','ROLE_CLIENTE'),
    )
```

Both firewalls work correctly, but in the target parameter of logout section does not work in either case, it always re addresses the root of my project.

Even if I modify with any url the target parameter always goes to the root of the project.

There I read that the logout handler should be modified, but it is not clear to me how it is configured and where it should be done

Can you give some recommendations to get both urls changed and working correctly?

Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parameter name is incorrect. Try to change it to `target_url`.

```
'logout'    =>  array(
    'logout_path' => '/clients/admin/logout',
    'target_url' => '/clients/login'
),
```

Comment: Hi Max thanks for the comment, What a mistake, if I have to sleep a little and rest the neurons rest, thank you very much for the observation, the problem it is resolve...